# Conversion operator int() failed for static_cast and reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, gcc, type-conversion, operators

I have following simple class with conversion:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<int p>
class Mod {
    int n;

    friend Mod operator+(const Mod &x, const Mod &y) {
        const int sum = x.n + y.n;

        if (sum < p) {
            Mod z(sum);
            return z;
        } else if (sum >= p) {
            Mod z2(sum - p);
            return z2;
        }
    }

    operator int() {
        if (p == 0) return n;
        if (p == 1) return 0;

        for (int r = 0; r <= abs(n); r++) {
            if (((r - n) % p) == 0) {
                return r;
            }
        }
    }

    friend Mod operator-(const Mod &x) {
        if (x.n == 0) return 0;

        Mod z(-static_cast<int>(x) + p);
        return z;
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Mod &x) {
        out << reinterpret_cast<int>(x); // invalid cast from type ‘const Mod<5>’ to type ‘int’ out << reinterpret_cast<int>(x);
        return out;
    }

public:
    Mod(int x) {
        n = x;
    }
};

int main() {
    Mod<5> z(3), x(2);

    cout << z + x << endl; // error: invalid cast from type ‘const Mod<5>’ to type ‘int’ out << reinterpret_cast<int>(x);
    cout << z << endl; //error: invalid cast from type ‘const Mod<5>’ to type ‘int’ out << reinterpret_cast<int>(x); // invalid cast from type ‘const Mod<5>’ to type ‘int’ out << reinterpret_cast<int>(x);
    cout << -x << endl; //error: invalid static_cast from type ‘const Mod<5>’ to type ‘int’ Mod z(-static_cast<int>(x) + p);

    return 0;
}
```

When I try compile and run them I see following message:

```
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/TestCpp.dir/main.cpp.o
/home/user/ClionProjects/TestCpp/main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Mod<5>&)’:
/home/user/ClionProjects/TestCpp/main.cpp:75:17:   required from here
/home/user/ClionProjects/TestCpp/main.cpp:56:13: error: invalid cast from type ‘const Mod<5>’ to type ‘int’
out << reinterpret_cast<int>(x); // invalid cast from type ‘const Mod<5>’ to type ‘int’ out << reinterpret_cast<int>(x);
^
/home/user/ClionProjects/TestCpp/main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Mod<5> operator-(const Mod<5>&)’:
/home/user/ClionProjects/TestCpp/main.cpp:77:14:   required from here
/home/user/ClionProjects/TestCpp/main.cpp:50:36: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘const Mod<5>’ to type ‘int’
Mod z(-static_cast<int>(x) + p);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For [static_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast),

> Converts between types using a combination of implicit and user-defined conversions.

User-defined conversion will be considered, but you're casting to `int` on `const` object, you should make `operator int()` const member function:

```
operator int() const {
               ~~~~~
    ...
}
```

For [reinterpret_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast),

> Converts between types by reinterpreting the underlying bit pattern.
>
> Unlike `static_cast`, but like `const_cast`, the `reinterpret_cast` expression does not compile to any CPU instructions. It is purely a compiler directive which instructs the compiler to treat the sequence of bits (object representation) of expression as if it had the type new_type.

So `reinterpret_cast<int>(x)` won't work anyhow, and user-defined conversion won't be considered.